# Import android gradle project in Intellij Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I try to share my LibGDX project between two OS Linux and Windows on my machine. The real problem is to import as gradle project (in Intellij Idea 15 and 2016 as well) from bitbucket shared code.

My problems starts when i try to mase some changes on Windows. Intellij idea just can't import project as gradle. I have still getting error message about not found BuildTools 23.0.2. Ok. I get it, but my Andoird SDK is up to date and I certainly downloaded this buildtools.

Ohh - on my unix system everything goes well, so I think I know what I'm doing. ;)

I'm stuck with it for a while now, so if You could give me any advice I will appriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have downloaded the required version of build tools there could be only one possible reason.

You must be having two different folders containing the android sdk. Make sure your intellij and project is configured to use the right one (where you have the required version of build tools)